# How dererialize response json in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i want to deserialize var in controller
how can i deserialize string s

```
public Boolean ajoutermodule(string nom, string s, int cv)
{
    return true;
}
```

string s is sent from javascript after stringify `var s = JSON.stringify(table)`
can someone help me how fix this issue and thank you very much

Comment: Your table is an existing model on your project?

Comment: What does your ajax call look like?

Comment: Can you post the content of `string s` when it reach the method?(use a breakpoint)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put this in your controller :

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            modules[] persons = js.Deserialize<modules[]>(s);
```

and creat class modules

```
 public class modules
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string nom { get; set; }

    }
```